# How is secure erase implemented on SSDs?

Tags: ssd, secure-erase

I've seen people talk about using it or that it works for erasing SSDs, but I can't find much on how it actually works.

Comment: "I've seen people…" more precisely to which document are you refering here? It might be an excellent one without any need to add anything. It might also be a piece of crap without any solid bases.

Comment: If you are talking about the ATA command, on SSDs it's often essentially equivalent to clearing the mapping in the FTL, making all the logical blocks read zero (on some drives you can achieve that with a full-drive TRIM as well). On some SEDs, it might additionally/instead trigger a regeneration of the encryption key.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really show your research.
Anyway… in broad strokes…

SSDs are hard to secure erase, because of all the 'un-advertised free space' they have. Modern OSes make them even harder to secure erase, especially for single files, because they spray backups, versions & intermediate saves everywhere.
The very best way to secure erase an SSD is for it to be fully encrypted before first use - then all you need to do is erase the encryption keys.

I've yet to see any product that *guarantees* [with citations] secure erase for single files.

Comment: Show what research? Also that doesn't answer the question either. I know that SSDs are hard to erase because of wear-leveling. I am asking what does the secure erase command that SSDs implement do, which is generally considered the best way to securely erase one if your SSD supports it. I never said anything about single files either... secure erase erases the whole drive.

Comment: "I've seen people talk about" … which people? Where? Show your research.  If you ever find one of these 'people' that absolutely guarantees they can find & eradicate *all traces* of any single file, including spurious system ghost copies, then the world will be beating a path to their door. You didn't define your 'secure'… in fact you didn't define anything, you just said you 'couldn't find much'. Show your research.

Comment: Single-file erasure can be difficult on spinning disks given journaling file systems but I'm no sure why you're emphasizing this point. It was not in the original question. Quite a few products are out there for whole-disk erasures on SSDs. They have been certified by NIST to purge data according to NIST 800-88 standards. A NIST certification is enough of a citation for me to accept the product.

Comment: @Tetsujin you should look up secure erase cause you don't seem to know what it is. It's a low-level command for to the controller itself that deletes everything, no it cannot be used for a single file. https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase
NVMes also have a similar thing.

A lot of the times the manager software the manufacturer provides can also issue the command.

Comment: @Tetsujin do people on stackexchange always love to bash on every single post without even doing research themselves to know what they are talking about? Cause it seems that way to me.

Comment: You didn't specify entire device or 'ATA Secure Erase'. You came in with a very vague question, to which I gave a very vague answer. GIGO. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @Tetsujin you clearly didn't read the post properly, secure erase is a common name of the command that everyone uses. What should I have specified? I asked how it is implemented by the manufacturers, it obviously is referring to the command modern SSDs support. What else would a secure erase that is implemented mean? You clearly didn't know about it, so you tried to tell that to me in turn out of your ignorance.

But we are done here.

Comment: I'm certainly done. You ask vague, you get vague. Edit your question to be precise, **with research & accurate definitions** so people don't have to guess at what you've *"seen people talk about"* & then maybe we can get a good answer to a good question. You now have my permission to stop nagging me in comments. **Fix your question. Show your research. Define your problem**

Comment: @Homoz FWIW I interpreted the question the same eay as Tetsujin, and would have provided a very similar answer to his.  The words "secure erase" dont imply the specific unspecified meaning you seem to think it does. Insulting a high ranking user (ie someone who has been here a while and is knowledgeable) is biting the hand that feeds you.

Comment: FWIW, different SSD manufacturers perform secure erase differently (and historically not always securely) - the good ones use an encrypted disk and throw away the key on erase.

Comment: @davidgo I didn't really insult them though, I just replied to what they said. Also high ranking user means nothing on online forums which work with karma. It's just karma games. This isn't the first time I post a question on stackexchange sites and get overly aggressive responses (and if you look it up on google, it's not just me who is complaining about the aggressive state of the site) so that might have helped. They imply I should do research but exactly what sort of research? I already said that I did some research and I didn't get many results on how it works.

Comment: @davidgo as for the secure erase, honestly it might be just me. But I can't think of much else called secure erase which is implemented on SSDs as a function to use. But well, you might be right, it could be interpreted differently. And mm, I have heard of what you say that manufacturers might implement it differently, but it's also mostly said to be work well and return the drive to its clean factory state. Like one explanation I have heard is that it gives a shock to all cells, clearing them, but I don't know how true that is.

Comment: @davidgo just some examples:

https://www.reddit.com/r/cscareerquestions/comments/8ewwjc/is_it_just_me_or_is_stack_overflow_an_incredibly/

https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/dc7vy5/what_is_going_on_within_stack_exchange_especially/

https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/7vh2rd/stackoverflow_in_a_nutshell/

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316651/so-how-many-people-have-stopped-participating-because-of-passive-aggressive-hara

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26014/why-is-the-stack-overflow-community-so-aggressive-about-question-criteria

Comment: @Hormoz - None of the URL's speak to the technical merits of the question.  If you don't like the way people at superuser.com interact, maybe you want to find another forum which is less focussed in its structure.   I do  point out that "experts" here - and we don't get any kind of remuneration for spending our free time answering questions - are more likely then your average person to be on the Autism spectrum.

Comment: Mostly Secure Erase DOES work well - just that if your data is super-duper secure you don't want to trust it.  I doubt it returns the disk to factory default as that would require unnecessary wear and take a long time, without solving the problem (which are cells that may have data on them but can't be overwritten) - but it could certainly make it appear to the OS as if it was reset to factory default.   Whoever was talking about giving a shock to the cells was talking absolute BS - all that would do is kill the device - and require an amount of power that an SSD is not designed to handle.

Comment: @davidgo The urls are about people complaining about stackexchange not the question of course. You might be right about that just not using the site though.. At least in my experience the "computer" places on stackexchange do give answers. Like this isn't as common, I do get answers. Now if you dare ask a physic or biology question... I find that stackexchange kinda works best for questions that are not super easy to answer, but are easy and quick enough to answer.

Comment: Anything outside the "norm" and you just get told how your question sucks instead of getting answers and then you find that you are spending more time reading how you suck comments instead of answers, mainly because people don't know the answer a lot of times. Like I remember a particular experience on physics after some arguing that I got several answers, and I was told that all of them are wrong by another person somewhere else. I still don't know who was right, but I am inclined to think the stackexchanges ones were wrong.

Comment: Mmm, but I wonder if there is any specific documentation for some manufacturer on how it exactly is implemented, I can't find any. Like not all SSDs support hardware encryption even, but even those can support secure delete without any implied encryption beforehand.

Comment: https://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA7-2608ENW.pdf    - Not a manufacturer guide to how its implemented, but NIST SP 800-88 does talk about the permissible ways to do this to comply with that standard - see page 36-38 of https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-88r1.pdf